# How to set up Googletest in VSCodium in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, googletest

I am trying to set up googletest for unit testing on my c++ project in vscodium. Though every tutorial I've seen hasn't shown how to actually set it up. So I am hoping one of you know how to set it up.

Comment: 'set it up', you mean install googletest on ubuntu, or set up vscodium to use googletest, or both?

Comment: set up vscodium to use googletest. I believe I have installed googletest already but am not sure how to set it up in vscodium. That being said if you wanted to explain both I wouldn't be mad :)